# Which is the correct way to start a letter ? - 1) Hi, Joe, or 2) Hi Joe,

Tags: punctuation

The question is whether we require a comma after 'Hi' or not.

Comment: Personally I never use Hi, because I don't recognise it as a word, certainly not one to use in written form. I would say 'Dear Joe'. There is no need for a comma between 'Dear' and 'Joe'.

Comment: Informal letters would not be so strict with the greeting. But if you're talking about business letters which fall under the formal category, "Hi" is not a practice. The comma is also insignificant, because you are not implying a pause here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with "Hi Joe," "Hello Joe," or "Dear Joe," Never put the comma right after "Hi."

Comment: No comma in *dear Joe,* but there should be one between *hello* or *hi* and *Joe.* We usually separate names with a pause (comma) when addressing people. *Dear* is different because it's part of the address (modifying the name).

Comment: Nope. It's always "Hi Joe" and then the comma. If you put "Hi, Joe," it's wrong.